# Update textbox using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm creating a textbox where the text will automatic update into mysql after user type and without submit.Problem now is the textbox doesn't not update the database. This is what i edited by refering to all the opinion below.yet still have some problem but is better than nothing display now.thanks.

here is the textbox input

```
  echo "<td class=\"align-center\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"comment\" id=\"comment\" onKeyPress=\"getComment($id,this)\" /></td>";
```

here is my javascript

```
function getComment(id, txt_box)
{
var value = txt_box.value;

    $.ajax({
        'url': 'updatecomment.php',
        'data': {"id": id, "comment": value},
        'success': function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            //TODO: use server response
        }
    });
}
```

and last is updatecomment.php

```
 <?php require_once("../includes/connection.php") ?>
 <?php require_once("../includes/functions.php") ?>

 <?php
     $id =$_GET['id'];
     $comment = $_GET['comment'];


     $query = "UPDATE tblinternapplication SET comment = '".mysql_real_escape_string($comment) ."' WHERE id = $id";
     $result = mysql_query($query, $connection);
 ?>
```

Comment: *sidenote:* stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: Double quot `"` is missing for `$query = "...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is your code

```
  echo "<td class=\"align-center\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"comment\" id=\"comment\" onPressKey=\"getComment($id,this.id)\" required/></td>";
```

Change this to

```
  echo "<td class=\"align-center\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"comment\" id=\"comment\" onKeyup=\"getComment('$id',this.value)\" required/></td>";
```

Basically when you pass values for javascript function if the value you pass is string or integer rather than variable enclose them in single quote like **getComment('$id',this.value)**

And another change that I added is onKeyup instead of onKeyPress. This is because **onKeyPress** event will happen **when a key is pressed down** and the function you called **will not have the last character you keyed in**. Whereas **onKeyPress** event will be **triggered when you release the key** i.e. after typing the character so you **will get all the characters entered** in the text box

similarly in Mysql query always enclose values in single quotes like following

```
     $query = "UPDATE tblinternapplication SET comment = '".mysql_real_escape_string($comment) ."' WHERE id = '$id'";
```

Hope you understand those changes

Comment: thanks your method is correct deliver the words. thank you so much!

Comment: This is not good....I gave the ans first and the same content that I gave in my ans...and your accepted ans is 36minutes after all of our ans....how can you do that.you accepted my ans and removed it and given to this which is 36min late of all our ans

Comment: @Gautam you where correct but on using onKeyPress you will not get all characters in the textbox since the event will trigger even before the user enters the character

Answer (score 1):

Your query has multiple errors. It should be:

```
$query = "UPDATE tblinternapplication SET comment = '".mysql_real_escape_string($comment) ."' WHERE id = $id";
```

while `mysql_*` should NOT be used as they are deprecated. use MySQLi or PDO instead. Watch out for SQL Injection too.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace

```
echo "<td class=\"align-center\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"comment\" id=\"comment\" onPressKey=\"getComment($id,this.id)\" required/></td>";
```

with

```
echo "<td class=\"align-center\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"comment\" id=\"comment\" onKeyPress=\"getComment($id,this.value)\" required/></td>";
```

**EDIT:**

```
echo "<td class=\"align-center\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"comment\" id=\"comment\" onKeyPress=\"getComment($id,this)\" required/></td>";
```

And at your function grab the value like

```
function getComment(txt_box, comment) {
    var value = txt_box.value;
}
```

You need to send the textbox value not again the id and try to update your update query like

```
$query = "UPDATE tblinternapplication 
          SET comment = ".mysql_real_escape_string($comment) ."
          WHERE id = $id";
```

Here $id is an integer na dyou have missed closing **"** at the last.And try to use mysqli_* statements or pdo statements instead of mysql_* statements due to they are deprecated

AND main thing make sure that comment column in DataBase should be data type **text** as per your comment

Comment: Is the any event like onPressKey

Comment: Thanku @Dineshkani I have updated it....I even not considered that event....Sorry for that

Comment: thanks, i tried to change to this.value but seem like nothing happen

Comment: Or do one thing....send this to the function and get the value there....See my edit

Comment: thanks now able to read what i'm typing in but still got a minor problem let say i type "test test" the sql only save "test tes"

Comment: Thenn you need to give the comment column type as text

Comment: I mentioned that in my ans also

Comment: Yes but main thing.....your comment is an text value so better to post it rather than send it in GET method...

Comment: all works will just the last word always missing a character like "letter" become "lette"

Comment: thats why I told you to change the data type of comment in Db to text

Comment: This is not good....I gave the ans first and the same content that I gave in my ans...and your accepted ans is 36minutes after all of our ans....how can you do that

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<td class=\"align-center\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"comment\" id=\"comment\" onKeyPress=\"javascript: return getComment($id,this.value);\" required/></td>";
```

You use `onPressKey` instead of `onKeyPress`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<td class=\"align-center\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"comment\" id=\"comment\" onPressKey=\"getComment($id,this.id)\" required/></td>";
```

should be

```
echo "<td class=\"align-center\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"comment\" id=\"comment\" onkeypress=\"getComment($id,this.id)\" required/></td>";
```